# Mounting windows drives in fedora with user account

Tags: mount, fedora

When I login fedora 9 with user account(instead of root), the windows drives dont get mounted, there is no entry in/ etc/fstab file for windows drives. But in file browser, it shows all windows drives. But when I do right click on them and try to mount, nothing happens. So how can I authorize to mount drives?

In root account, they automatically get mounted.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't in /etc/fstab, then I aasume that something aalong the lines of autofs is mounting your drive - the system is just seeing it as a removable drive like a USB stick or something, but only working when root permissions are around.

To solve the problem, you need to create a suitable entry in /etc/fstab, which should mount it as you like before it gets automounted by autofs; something like:

```
UUID=1234ABCD12345678   /Windows      ntfs-3g rw,defaults 0 0
```

You can get the UUID by using the command:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```